# Достать число из публичного ключа RSA

Tags: c#, криптография

У меня есть публичный ключ алгоритма RSA, он выглядит так:

```
<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>1p3TaiUejpOPpeiaElNa1TWcoLyGcExLNuQC/6+jzqLtX5y8S5QSI5gKhLAzZhxX</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>

1p3TaiUejpOPpeiaElNa1TWcoLyGcExLNuQC/6+jzqLtX5y8S5QSI5gKhLAzZhxX

AQAB
```

Первая срока это ключ, вторая - открытая экспонента, очевидно, что они закодированы в `base64`.

Вопрос. Как извлечь именно числа?

Comment: Там просто байты, соответствующие числу: декодирование экспоненты дает 0x01 0x00 0x01, что соответствует 65537. Только непонятно как байты хранятся: сначала младшие или сначала старшие...

Comment: Т.е. если байт равен 247 то это и есть число 247? А как их записывать, подряд??

Comment: Если байт равен 247 - там 247. Но если у вас число записано несколькими байтами все становится сложнее. То же 65537 представлено 3 байтами: 0x01, 0x00, 0x01 и получается оно так: 1 * 256^0 + 0*256^1 + 1*256^2 = 65537. Соответственно, нужно знать какие байты записаны сначала: старшие или младшие.

Comment: Спасибо огромное.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Пожалуйста, опубликуйте комментарии в виде ответа.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Не ясен порядок байт, поэтому ответ неоднозначный и не очень полезный.

Answer (score 1):

Указанный пример - это XML-файл. Разобрать его можно используя [System.Xml.Linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.linq(v=vs.110).aspx), где получатся две строки, которые в набор байтов превращаются использованием [System.Convert.FromBase64String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 0):

Параметры можно декодировать напрямую (как base64), или через импорт в RSA CSP (т.к. ваш xml - это результат экспорта). Порядок байт - [big endian](http://blog.wezeku.com/2011/03/12/net-rsaparameters-endianness/). Преобразовать в число можно через BigInteger co со сменой порядка.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

class Program
{
    static BigInteger BigEndianToBigInteger(byte[] data)
    {
        return new BigInteger(
           data    
           .Reverse() // смена порядка
           .Concat(new byte[] { 0 }) // принудительный 0 в начале для получения положительного числа
           .ToArray() 
       );
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var xmlString = @"<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>1p3TaiUejpOPpeiaElNa1TWcoLyGcExLNuQC/6+jzqLtX5y8S5QSI5gKhLAzZhxX</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>";
        var provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        provider.FromXmlString(xmlString);
        RSAParameters parameters = provider.ExportParameters(false);

        Console.WriteLine(BigEndianToBigInteger(parameters.Modulus));
        Console.WriteLine(BigEndianToBigInteger(parameters.Exponent));
    }
}
```

самописная реализация RSA [есть на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702718/public-key-encryption-with-rsacryptoserviceprovider), код для преобразования я взял оттуда.